# Mostrar propiedades de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, variables, session, object

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que tiene un objeto que se llama SessionContext este objeto tiene variables de sesión que en algunas oportunidades son persistentes, dentro de la aplicación (No la hice yo) existen muchos get y Set por ejemplo:

```
var ctx = new SessionContext;
var NumberTicket = ctx.get("NumberTicket");
```

Yo puedo acceder a variables de sesión a través de su "Keyname" que es el que está entre comillas no puedo acceder a la definición del objeto porque se encuentra en el Kernel de la aplicación, aquí viene mi pregunta:

Existe alguna manera de imprimir todos los posibles Keyname que almacenan variables dentro de ese objeto? a través de la aplicación soy capaz de enviar el contenido de una variable a un archivo plano, como un XML. quisiera saber todas las variables de sesión que almacena ese objeto

Comment: Hola, en SO[EN] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object de todas formas con un console.log desde la consola del navegador se puede observar, pero sí es un objeto que puede cambiar dinámicamente mejor saberlo de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Rafael, dices que no puedes acceder a la definición del objeto, pero sin embargo pareces poder acceder al código fuente. ¿Qué te impide realizar una depuración de la llamada a la función en tiempo de ejecución?